# Quickest way to loop through dynamic rows

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have seen a previous post about this, and have tried to apply it but i have been unsuccesful.

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim varray As Variant

Sheets("Original").Select
varray = Sheets("Original").Range("A10:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = 10 To UBound(varray, 1)
    If Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
        Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = Cells(i, 16).Value
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20305
        Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
        Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It skips the whole for Loop and goes to End Sub. Any assistance?

Thanks

Comment: What row does your data start in?  10?

Comment: When you step through the code, what's the value of `varray`?

Comment: @tompreston yes it starts in row 10

Comment: @SkipIntro the value is "Empty"

Comment: First you are putting part of your sheet `A10:A100` (or whatever the last row is) into an array and then you iterate through the array. Yet, you are not using / referring to the array in the loop but rather work on the sheet. That doesn't seem to make sense. If you want to go fast then you should do all in the array (only) and then (in one run) make all the changes on the sheet. You are loosing the speed advantage of the array here. Also, some of your code is not qualified (such as `Rows.Count` or all the sheet references in the loop).

Comment: I would suggest that if `varray` is `empty` you first investigate why that is so.

Comment: `varray` can be empty possibly due to no data being present or if it is referencing the incorrect sheet when capturing the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the code you have there. I have tried to address them in my script below. Unfortunately there is no example of your data you working with. Have a look and let me know if something is not working.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'Get used to declaring your worksheet
    'and then reference that worksheet when wanting to access data form it.
    Dim OrigSht As Worksheet
    Set OrigSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Original")

    Dim LastRowColA As Long
    LastRowColA = OrigSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Not sure why you wanted to use an Array, seeing as you dont use it in the loop.
    'Unless you use it in some other code and this is a extract from other code.
    Dim varray As Variant
    varray = OrigSht.Range("A10:A" & LastRowColA).Value

    'Using UBound could present errors if there was less than 10 lines of data _
    it would then step the loop because the  to value is less than the start
    'Rather use the last row of column A as a end of the For loop

    'The problem with editing a list of data form the begining of a list _
    is that the list becomes longer as you add information, so when adding _
    or deleting lines you always want to start at the end og the list
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LastRowColA To 10 Step -1

        With OrigSht
            If .Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then

                .Cells(i + 1, 16).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Value = .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value
                .Cells(i + 1, 6).Value = .Cells(i, 16).Value
                .Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = 20305
                .Cells(i + 1, 11).Value = ""
                .Cells(i + 1, 12).Value = ""
                .Cells(i + 1, 15).Value = ""
                .Cells(i + 1, 16).Value = ""
            End If

        End With
    Next

End Sub
```